# escape blacklist html tags outside of code tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a (white)list of tags that I will allow as html *outside* of `code` tags. For any html written within `<code>` tags, I want to use regex in javascript to replace the < and > characters with &#60; and &62;

So the `<b>` symbols should be replaced within `<code><b>bold</b></code>`, but not the `<code>` tags themselves - they should remain as html.

I don't want to allow the `<script>` tag outside of the `<code>` block, so I wont have 'script' in my whitelist. If the script tag is within the code tags, then the ascii replace should take place.

This is quite similar to how the RTE works here on stackoverflow.

I need to do this all client-side using javascript + regex. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Parsing HTML (or XML) using regular expressions is not a very good idea. You need a real markup parser.

Comment: What about a `<code>` tag that contains `</code>` as part of its code?  http://blog.slaks.net/2013-06-10/jekyll-endraw-in-code

Comment: Don't use a regexp to parse HTML (spoiler: you can't) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I saw this coming, but my queries are based around code tags where I would need to use regex to differentiate between rules for different types of text.. for all you know, I could ALSO be using a parser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do something like this

```
function changeCode() {
    var codeTags = document.getElementsByTagName('code');
    for(var i = 0; i < codeTags.length; i++) {
        var current = codeTags[i];
        current.innerHTML = current.innerHTML.replace(/</g, "&#60;").replace(/>/g, "&#62;");
    }
}
window.onload = changeCode; //executes after the DOM is ready
```

But it needs some work on it, it just changes the HTML of the `<code>` tag escaping the `<,>` chars with a simple regex. Anyway you should add something like a common class or name so that the loop can execute the function only on the code tags you want.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < codeTags.length; i++) {
        var current = codeTags[i];
        if (current.className.indexOf('someclass') !== -1 || current.name !== 'somename') continue;
        current.innerHTML = current.innerHTML.replace(/</g, "&#60;").replace(/>/g, "&#62;");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for actually answering my question unlike some others :)